# XamlFiles parameter is not supported by XamlGtask

Tags: xamarin

I just loaded my xaml solution and tried debugging and I got these errors. Earlier in the day I updated my Xaml but I ran into errors with the corresponding Xcode version. I enabled the managed header and started to download the latest version of Xcode that I could (9.2) and that worked this morning, but it has now stopped working. Any ideas?

> /Users/rehamathur/Projects/TestApp/packages/Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.583944/build/netstandard2.0/Xamarin.Forms.targets(4,4):
>   Error MSB4064: The "XamlFiles" parameter is not supported by the
>   "XamlGTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a
>   settable public instance property. (MSB4064) (TestApp.iOS)
>
> /Users/rehamathur/Projects/TestApp/packages/Xamarin.Forms.3.1.0.583944/build/netstandard2.0/Xamarin.Forms.targets(3,3):
>   Error MSB4063: The "XamlGTask" task could not be initialized with its
>   input parameters.  (MSB4063) (TestApp.iOS)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update:

After some more searching around I came upon this github thread dealing with the exact same issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2975.

I updated my android packages and changed the target to the latest version, cleaned the solution and restarted the IDE and that worked.

If anybody, however, can explain what the error means, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: for me, I was focusing on iOS right now, so I've unloaded the Android project and it works fine.

Answer (score 9):

I also have this error. However, I had already update the Xamarin.Forms in Nuget. The error still occurred.

After a few hours searching and trying, I opened the .csproj file by external code editor and found some lines that import different version of Xamarin.Forms

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
.....
<Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.5.0.129452\build\Xamarin.Forms.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.5.0.129452\build\Xamarin.Forms.props')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.5.0.129452\build\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.5.0.129452\build\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
```

And somethings like this

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.193\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.5.0.129452\build\Xamarin.Forms.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.5.0.129452\build\Xamarin.Forms.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.5.0.129452\build\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.5.0.129452\build\Xamarin.Forms.targets'))" />
```

So. I decided to remove all lines that contains old version of Xamarin.Forms. Then, Reload the project Clean and Build again.

The error disappeared!

Answer (score 5):

A pretty important addition from the answer of "StephaneDelcroix" there

- make sure ALL of your project targets the same version of the XF nuget

I have reviewed my project and discovered that I have overlooked my PCL referencing old XF version. After upgrading and retargeting packages and following remaining steps the error was gone.