# Error upgrading Xamarin.Forms from 2.x.x to 3.x.x

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

I got a problem upgrading Xamarin.Forms nuget library from 2.x.x to 3.x.x. The error I got is MSB4063 and MSB4064 as below:

> /Users/user/.nuget/packages/xamarin.forms/3.6.0.344457/build/Xamarin.Forms.targets(4,4):
>   Error MSB4064: The "XamlFiles" parameter is not supported by the
>   "XamlGTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a
>   settable public instance property. (MSB4064) (App.Core)

And:

> /Users/user/.nuget/packages/xamarin.forms/3.6.0.344457/build/Xamarin.Forms.targets(3,3):
>   Error MSB4063: The "XamlGTask" task could not be initialized with its
>   input parameters.  (MSB4063) (App.Core)

[image]

I checked and some people are able to sort it out by clean and rebuild, or by delete the bin and obj folder from the project and build it again. However, none of them work for me. Any help would be really appreciate.

This is the list of all nuget libs I have on my project. Some people also mentioned that it could be conflict between libraries using old version of Xamarin.Forms. I tried to upgrade all of them but still got the same issue.

[image]

I am on Visual Studio for Mac - Community version 8.0.5 (build 9), and I am on Mac OS 10.14.2.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest you only update the Xamarin Forms package before updating anything else so that it updates to the correct version of its dependencies!

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273331/xamlfiles-parameter-is-not-supported-by-xamlgtask) to see if it helps.

Comment: I think I tried all of them but none of the method work. Is there any official fix for it yet? Assuming lots of people should have the same error upgrading from 2.x.x to 3x.x.

Comment: This may caused by many different reasons because each situation of people is different. So, I don't think there is any official fix for it.